# Main progress for multiple upload progress (Android)

Tags: java, android, upload, queue, progress-bar

i have a problem to monitoring global progress of upload queue.

Here is my files

1. foo.jpg [state : uploaded]
2. bar.jpg [state : uploaded]
3. obama.jpg [state : uploaded]
4. michelle.jpg [state : 84%]
5. hillary.jpg [state : pending]
6. trump.jpg [state : pending]

normally, i used (uploaded * 100) / totalFilesQueue;

by the percentage increase while one upload ends.
is there a where to calculate the gloabal percent with 2 parameters ** SINGLE UPLOAD PROGRESS & GLOBAL PROGRESS [(uploaded * 100) / totalFilesQueue]??

Comment: What do you mean by "*taking account of the single percentage and the overall*"?

Comment: i want to calculate the global percentatge with 2 parameters
the global percentage and the single percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int totalPayloadSize = payload1 + payload1 + .......;
int totalUploadedSize = 0;
float globalUploadedPercentace = 0;

void updateLoop(int uploadedBytes){
    totalUploadedSize += uploadedBytes;
    globalUploadedPercentace = (totalUploadedSize * 100 * 1f)/totalPayloadSize;

}
```

you can omit 1f multiplier if you do not want floating point precision.

Answer (score 0):

( The sum of every SINGLE UPLOAD PROGRESS ) / totalFilesQueue * 100

Of course if the ( The add of every SINGLE UPLOAD PROGRESS ) is in base 100 and you want a result of decimal

Or Just ( The sum of every SINGLE UPLOAD PROGRESS ) / totalFilesQueue